# Grouped pie chart segments in d3js using .padAngle()

Tags: d3.js, pie-chart

How would I add padding between some groups of segments in a donut/pie chart using d3?

**UPDATE**

I am using the d3.svg.arc shape generator and .padAngle(paddingFunction) where  paddingFunction is defined as:

```
var paddingFunction = function(d,i) { return i%1==0 ? 0.1 : 0 };
```

This image is using the paddingFunction described above.

[image]

But if I change the padding function to this:

```
var paddingFunction = function(d,i) { return i%5==0 ? 0.1 : 0 };
```

I get this image:

[image]

Shouldn't the code return two groups of segments with a gap in-between?

Complete code:

```
 // magic numbers
var t = 2 * Math.PI;
var arcHeight = 100;
var innerRadius = 50;
var hours = 10;

 function postion(i,offset) {
  offset = offset || 0;
  return i*(t / hours) + offset*(t / hours)
}

var paddingFunction = function(d,i) { return i%1==0 ? 0.1 : 0 };

// arc generators
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(function(d,i) { return innerRadius; })
  .outerRadius(function(d,i) { return innerRadius + arcHeight; })
  .startAngle(function(d, i){ return postion(d.hour);})
  .endAngle(function(d, i){ return postion(d.hour,1);})
    .padAngle(paddingFunction);


// data
var data = d3.range(0,hours);
data = data.map(function(d) {
  return {
    hour: d,
    color: Math.random(),
  }
});

// Scales
var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, 1])
.interpolate(d3.interpolateRgb)
.range(["#ffffff", "#ffba19"]);

// render viz
var svg = d3.select("svg")
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(320, 320)");

var select = svg.selectAll(".fore").data(data).enter();
select.append("path")
  .classed("fore", true)
  .style({
    "stroke": "black",
    "stroke-width": 1,
    "fill": function(d) { return colorScale(d.color); }
    })
  .attr("d", arc);
```

**UPDATE 2**

Seems that I misunderstood how the .padAngle() method works. It adds padding on BOTH sides of a segment, I thought it added a gap between segments.

Is there an alternative method in d3 which adds a gap between segements (whilst recalculating the area of the segments so they all keep their proportions)?

Running code: http://blockbuilder.org/GitNoise/13f38aa8f4f2f06dd869

Comment: Use [`.padAngle()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pie-Layout#padAngle).

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my rather vague question with a lot more information.

Comment: And `.padAngle()` doesn't work for you?

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work when using a function inside .padAngle().

Comment: Hmm, it looks like it should work this way. Have you tried returning a non-zero value in exactly one case?

Comment: Oh I see, .padAngle() adds padding on both sides of one particular segment. I thought it added a gap on one side of the segment. Anyways, the question still stands... how do I group some segments and then add padding on both sides of them? (or add a gap between the groups which would be preferable)

Comment: I don't think you can do that with the pie layout. You'd have to write your own implementation.